# convert java into json

Tags: java, json

how to use json-simple in java to generate the json below?  I don't know how to get the **data =** part.  Thank you in advance.

> data = '[{"name" : "Harry", "age" : "32"}]';

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
                var mydata = JSON.parse(data);

        var arr = [];
        for(var x in mydata) {
            arr.push(mydata[x].name);
            arr.push(mydata[x].age);
        }
        for(var y in arr ) {
            alert(arr[y]);
        }

    });     
</script>
```

Comment: that's not json, maybe some javascript

Comment: That is a `java.util.List` with one `java.util.Map`.

Comment: You're not getting the `data =` part from your JSON library because that part isn't JSON. Can't you just concatenate it onto the result yourself though?

Comment: @PeterMmm If I only get the '[{"name" : "Harry", "age" : "32"}]'; to start with then I cannot use JSON.parse(), so how could I get the value of name and age?

Comment: @RC. You are right, thank you.

Comment: @ChrisMartin Thank you for the info, but if I concatenate the data= part, then I cannot use JSON.parse(data), so how can I get the value of name and age? Thank you

Comment: Runs [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ky1rxqaa/). Probably your `data` isn't in JSON format. What is the actual value of `data` when the script runs?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for creating a JSONObject from Java,below is the code.
It creates a JSONObject and adds the strings mentioned.

```
JSONObject element =  new JSONObject();
element.put("name","Harry");
element.put("age","32");
JSONArray data = new JSONArray();
data.add(element);
System.out.println(data);
```

Output : [{"name":"Harry","age":"32"}]

I am assuming you are calling a servlet or some other web service to get this data.